# Testing autolayout with XCTest

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, xctest

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to test the layout of an iOS view in unit tests when using autolayout. Right now I try to simply initialize the view controller, and then check the frames of the views. However, the frame on each view remains origin=(x=0, y=0) size=(width=0, height=0).

```
- (void)setUp {
    [super setUp];

    _viewController = [[AddPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    _viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    [_viewController view];
}

- (void)testViewsAreInsideWindow {
    [self checkIfViewIsInsideWindow:_viewController.txtfNewPlayer];
    [self checkIfViewIsInsideWindow:_viewController.btnNewPlayer];
    [self checkIfViewIsInsideWindow:_viewController.tblPlayers];
}

- (void)checkIfViewIsInsideWindow:(UIView *)view {
    CGRect windowFrame = _viewController.view.frame;
    CGRect viewFrame = view.frame;
    XCTAssertTrue(CGRectContainsRect(windowFrame, viewFrame));
}
```

I've tried adding

```
[_viewController.view needsUpdateConstraints];
```

or

```
[_viewController.view updateConstraints];
```

or

```
[_viewController updateViewConstraints];
```

or

```
[_viewController viewWillAppear:YES];
```

but none of them have helped.

Is it at all possible to get autolayout to run when using XCTest?

Comment: Have you tried `setNeedsLayout` followed by `layoutIfNeeded`? You can get layout to run in tests, I do it here : https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout/blob/master/Example/AutoLayoutTests/AutoLayoutConstraintsSpec.m but that doesn't have a view controller, just views.

Comment: OK, I'll add it as an answer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried `setNeedsLayout` followed by `layoutIfNeeded`?

You can definitely get layout to run in tests, I do it [here](https://github.com/jrturton/UIView-Autolayout/blob/master/Example/AutoLayoutTests/AutoLayoutConstraintsSpec.m), but that doesn't have a view controller, just views.

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you are trying to see is whether elements are visible to the user. You may use isHittable property in XCUIElement.

From documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1500561-ishittable

> isHittable returns true if the element exists and can be clicked, tapped, or pressed at its current location. It returns false if the element does not exist, is offscreen, or is covered by another element.