# Testing views constraints programmatically ( In Unit test )

Tags: swift, unit-testing

I have built all my UI programmatically without using IB in Xcode. Now I want to assert that the constraints are correct in my Unit Tests ( Yes, not in UI testing ).

I have some constraints like these :

```
footer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
footer.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
footer.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
footer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.08).isActive = true
```

Now I want to test this in my unit testing. I can assert that the footer is not nil, and that it has the expected properties except for the dimensions, as they show up as 0 always. For instance, this is something I tried but it did not work :

```
XCTAssertTrue(subject.getFooterView().frame.origin.y == subject.view.frame.origin.y)
```

Which I think should be true but it fails. If I print the values of each property, I can see that the value **subject.view.frame.origin.y** is *414* but the value **subject.getFooterView().frame.origin.y** is always *zero*.

Same happens with all the other properties, for instance **frame.size.width**, etc, are always *zero* for my footer.

Can someone help me to understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this isn't giving you the result that you want is because of how AutoLayout works.  You will not be able to access the frame.size.width value until after the viewDidLayoutSubviews method is called of the View Controller, and if you're testing, you're probably running this test before this method is called.

Look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26632534/testing-autolayout-with-xctest).

He mentions trying setNeedsLayout followed by layoutIfNeeded?

Comment: This was EXACTLY what was missing!! Thanks!